# How to merge two multi dimensional arrays in php?

Tags: php

How to do it? Please give me a solution.

Comment: How would that be different from merging any two single-dimensional arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same way as merging a standard array.

```
array_merge($arrayone[0],$arraytwo[0]);
```

Answer (score 4):

You may be interested in PHP's [`array_merge_recursive`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/array-merge-recursive) function.

Answer (score 2):

You can merge arrays by using [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php).

If you want more specific help, edit your question and make it more specific.